# How to manage URLs with a lot of query params?

Tags: php, design-patterns, url, get, param

How are you managing big URLs (with a lot of query parameters) in your app?

For example, look this link from ebay (don't click the link is just an example of a big URL):

http://www.ebay.com/sch/Cameras-Photo-/625/i.html?LH_ItemCondition=1&LH_Price=15..500%40c&rt=nc&LH_Auction=1&LH_BIN=1&_nkw=nikon&_catref=1&_clu=2&_fcid=12&_fln=1&_localstpos=&_mPrRngCbx=1&_sc=1&_sop=15&_stpos=&_trksid=p3286.c0.m283&gbr=1

You can see a lot of params, many of them with strange and short names like "_f", "_sc" etc.

You can't use those params in your app, you need to convert to something more "readable":

```
 $readableName = $_GET['_f'];
```

but then you end with a lot of vars, and probably you need all of them in a function, so, instead of a new var for every query param we can use an array:

```
$readableParams['readableName'] = $_GET['_f'];
```

But then we end with a big array with an arbitrary structure, so I think the best idea is to have a VO (DTO) for those params, something like:

```
$filterVo = new FilterVo();
$filterVo->readableName = $_GET['_f'];
```

That's OK, but where we put that code? I mean, where is the best place to make the conversion from "rare quer params" to "clear value objects"?
Because we also need the inverse process, so we can create a VO with data, and then generate a URL with the correct query params from that VO.

Inside the VO? 
Helper URL class?
View Model base class?

**How are you managing these URLs with a lot of params?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's interesting that you brought up the input names are cryptic. I am going to answer in general sense (not only PHP specifics) on what I've seen in my projects that I think pertinent to this topic. The general approach:

- The form variables are normally mapped to an object. It's a VO in PHP or Beans in Java. This would be the most readable forms of transformation (in my opinion) as it gives context to the HTML forms that are being converted
- In many cases, I've seen some kind of Form Utilities Helper class that will handle the transformation to and from. However, this is not a specific hardcoded transformation, most of the transformation is very structured and generic. For example, it takes all the getters/setters method and use that as a form name. For example, I might have `getUsername()` in my object, then the Form Utilities will translate it into `<input name="username"/>` for example.
- Optionally, you could also override the default mapping via mapping override. This could be in the form of :

  - Configuration file, for example an XML File that maps the instance variable to the the form variable. In the example above, such mapping could be to map username instance variable to a more cryptic form variable named u
  - Language feature such as annotation in Java or Attribute in C#. The language feature would allow the mapping to be made without configuration file but inline in the object source code itself
- I've seen projects that would have base class for the VO/Bean that has `fromForm(input)` and `toForm()` that utilize the Form Utilities mentioned above. It provides convenience to the developers so they don't have to deal with Form Utilities but simply call `toForm()` and `fromForm(input)` from their object to handle the transformation

Now given the pattern above, for cryptic form fields, I normally see:

- Create VO object to represent the fields
- Create mapping configuration to map the cryptic field to the actual instance variable with logical name
- Either use Form Utilities helper class directly, or if the Form Utilities used in the base class, use the convenience methods `toForm()` and `fromForm(input)`

Comment: I have choosen for generating *all* my links with a helper class (my views/view_model uses that class) they accept a VO and return the link. And the inverse process is inside the proper controller_action. Anyway I'm not sure of this solution because the code for transforming VO to RequestParams is in two different places now. And I don't know how to solve this with POST params (a POST request is no a link, so maybe I need an extra FormParamsGenerator helper). Maybe using toParam and fromParam in the VO is cleaner (even more if we use an interface), I was hoping this was a common pattern :(

Comment: I agree that using to and from in the VO itself is cleaner. As I wrote in my answer, the to and from in VO can call the Form Utilities (the helper class) in order to the work. As for your POST vs. GET param, what you want to do is generalize the data structure into a table structure of key-value pair that you pass to your helper class (instead of making it GET vs. POST specific data) and have extension of this helper class as PostFormUtilities and GetFormUtilities and their job is to translate the specific data of POST/GET and translate it into the generalized table key-value data.

Comment: To answer your question whether that's common pattern, the answer is yes. Not only for mapping between HTTP Parameters but is a common pattern for any kind of mapping (in particular DB to VO mapping or XML to VO mapping). In many of these scenarios, you will have equivalent to and from function in either the VO or in Utility class. If you need more clarification, let me know and I could update the answer

Comment: The problem with the VO::from and VO::to is that we are puting code that belongs to the controller or request inside our VO I don't like that, and also we are fixing the relation between request params and VO (you can't have 2 actions that receives different request params but generates the same VO). I think I will continue with the Link::to and ControllerAction::from solution, it's true that parsing is in two places but those places are the right places I think. And the POST params are not a problem because they belongs to just one view so maybe we don't need nothing special for that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most of those parameters are auto-generated. I have seen this kind of behaviour in a lot of ASP.NET apps. And I hate .NET for doing such stuff, but I don't want to start that topic *again*.

Most of the time these additional parameters are generated by drop-in *modules*. These work in an automated way doing some stuff that isn't directly reflected in the app (the part the developer of the application is writing at least), or assist in other tasks. It's a way to maintain state across requests.

On the other hand you could implement such a mechanism you describe. In an MVC environment this task would be handled by the Controller. This only makes sense if you have A LOT of GET parameters getting passed. You should try to avoid this kind of practice from a beginning.

Comment: Yes I'm working with an MVC framework, and the problem is at really that, I have a lot of GET parameters (like the link from ebay). The controller is the right place to read those parameters and hence convert to some VO/DTO, but where to put the inverse process? how do you generate the link? this should be part of the View (or View_Model), but then we have the conversion and mapping of URL to/from VO in two different places.

Comment: Theoretically this task would also be the controller's responsibility, since the controller is responsible for handling "requests", regardless if incoming our preparing the next one.

Comment: I think that's wrong, generating links is a task for the View, or even better, the View_Model if you are using that pattern. My controllers doesn't know anything about how to generate the view, just the view_model they need to call, also, the links can be generated by any view, and hence any controller from your viewpoint, that brings a lot of DRY problems. Right now I have a helper class for generating links, that class uses parameters and the Route class and is used by my View_Model.